# Use OrderedDict or ordered list?(novice)

Tags: python, filter, ordereddictionary

(Using Python 3.4.3)
Here's what I want to do: I have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are the number of times that string occurs in file. I need to output which string(s) occur with the greatest frequency, along with their frequencies (if there's a tie for the most-frequent, output all of the most-frequent).

I had tried to use OrderedDict. I can create it fine, but I struggle to get it to output specifically the most frequently occurring. I can keep trying, but I'm not sure an OrderedDict is really what I should be using, since I'll never need the actual OrderedDict once I've determined and output the most-frequent strings and their frequency. A fellow student recommended an ordered list, but I don't see how I'd preserve the link between the keys and values as I currently have them.

Is OrderedDict the best tool to do what I'm looking for, or is there something else? If it is, is there a way to filter/slice(or equivalent) the OrderedDict?

Comment: No, you could use an ordinary `dict` while collecting the data, then you put the data (frequency, key-pairs) in a list and sorts it.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `collections.Counter`, not `.OrderedDict`. Then you can just use the `most_common` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `sorted` with a proper key function, in this case you can use `operator.itemgetter(1)` which will sorts your items based on values.

```
from operator import itemgetter

print sorted(my_dict.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in two steps. First sort your dictionary entries by their frequency so that the highest frequency is first.

Secondly use Python's `groupby` function to take matching entries from the list. As you are only interested in the highest, you stop after one iteration. For example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_dict = {"a" : 8, "d" : 3, "c" : 8, "b" : 2, "e" : 2}

for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print list(g)
    break
```

This would display:

```
[('a', 8), ('c', 8)]
```

As `a` and `c` are equal top.

If you remove the `break` statement, you would get the full list:

```
[('a', 8), ('c', 8)]
[('d', 3)]
[('b', 2), ('e', 2)]
```